# Cannot start skydns

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to install kubernetes on ubutnu (bare-metal installation).
I install one master and one node and it looks fine.
I installed the ui addon without a problem but when I tried to install the dns addon the pod restart itself continuously.

in kube-apiserver logs I get:

```
E1218 12:56:15.298118       5 handlers.go:37] Unable to authenticate the request due to an error: crypto/rsa: verification error
I1218 12:56:15.298220       5 handlers.go:131] GET /api/v1/services: (534.467µs) 401 [[kube2sky/v0.20.2 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/unknown] 172.27.35.39:33013]
E1218 12:56:15.298396       5 handlers.go:37] Unable to authenticate the request due to an error: crypto/rsa: verification error
I1218 12:56:15.298469       5 handlers.go:131] GET /api/v1/endpoints: (493.5µs) 401 [[kube2sky/v0.20.2 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/unknown] 172.27.35.39:33014]
I1218 12:56:16.001321       5 handlers.go:131] GET /healthz: (83.326µs) 0 [[Go 1.1 package http] 127.0.0.1:42096]
E1218 12:56:16.303274       5 handlers.go:37] Unable to authenticate the request due to an error: crypto/rsa: verification error
E1218 12:56:16.303274       5 handlers.go:37] Unable to authenticate the request due to an error: crypto/rsa: verification error
```

And in the kube2sky container log I get the following errors:

```
E1218 12:57:51.713651       1 reflector.go:136] Failed to list   *api.Service: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials (get services)
E1218 12:57:51.713850       1 reflector.go:136] Failed to list *api.Endpoints: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials (get endpoints)
```

looks to me like I have a problem with service account and token but I looked in the kube2sky instance and I see that I have a token in /tmp/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount directory and the ca.crt is the correct ca of the cluster

I am using:
ubuntu 14.04
kubernetes 1.1.2
add I try to create the dns addon from the addon directory of kubernetes 1.1.2

Comment: I have installed kubernetes you had exactly same. Please check mountPath in kube2sky container. I'm using volumeMounts for token as follows.                "volumeMounts": [
                    {
                        "name": "default-token-npk63",
                        "readOnly": true,
                        "mountPath": "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount"
                    }
                ],

Answer (score 6):

I had this same problem after updating the certificate and key of the api-server. I fixed the DNS service after removing the secret:

```
# Search the secret name
kubectl get pod --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns -o yaml | grep -A1 serviceaccount

# Delete the current secret
kubectl delete secret/<name-of-the-secret> --namespace=kube-system
```

I also need to restart the whole POD, don't know if there is a better approach:

```
kubectl delete svc/kube-dns rc/kube-dns-v9 --namespace=kube-system
kubectl create -f dns-addon.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

As i found it's not issue with skydns, but rather with Kubernetes itself. If i put this rc/service in any different namespace it works perfect. I had this issue with 1.1.4 Kubernetes