# Unable to get kubernetes dashboard up and running

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to install multi-node kubernetes setup for the first time with following versions:

> KUBE_VERSION=1.4.0, FLANNEL_VERSION=0.5.0, ETCD_VERSION=2.2.0

My setup has :  2 nodes and 1 master + node.  All these nodes (in my case are VMs) are running Ubuntu 14.04 with 1 GB RAM and 25 GB hardisk.

I have followed the below link to carry out the installation

> http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/ubuntu/

Once I was able to get the cluster up (verified using `kubectl get cs)`, I tried running `KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=ubuntu ./deployAddons.sh` to install the dns and ui addons.

Following is the output of the command:

```
> Deploying DNS on Kubernetes replicationcontroller "kube-dns-v20"
> created service "kube-dns" created Kube-dns rc and service is
> successfully deployed.
> 
> Creating Kubernetes Dashboard replicationController
> replicationcontroller "kubernetes-dashboard-v1.4.0" created Creating
> Kubernetes Dashboard service service "kubernetes-dashboard" created
```

However when trying to access the dashboard using the url http://master-ip:8080/ui , i get the below message

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "no endpoints available for service \"kubernetes-dashboard\"",
  "reason": "ServiceUnavailable",
  "code": 503
}
```

I saw my pods being stuck in the below state:

```
kube-dns-v20-nskvk                  1/3       CrashLoopBackOff   18         
kubernetes-dashboard-v1.4.0-4py1m   0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   10
```

Following is the log of my dashboard pod

```
>  kubectl logs kubernetes-dashboard-v1.4.0-4py1m  -n kube-system
> Starting HTTP server on port 9090 Creating API server client for
> https://192.168.3.1:443 Error while initializing connection to
> Kubernetes apiserver. This most likely means that the cluster is
> misconfigured (e.g., it has invalid apiserver certificates or service
> accounts configuration) or the --apiserver-host param points to a
> server that does not exist. Reason: the server has asked for the
> client to provide credentials
```

Following is the output of my services

```
kubectl get svc -n kube-system
NAME                   CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         
kube-dns               192.168.3.10    <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   
kubernetes-dashboard   192.168.3.229   <none>        80/TCP          

kubectl get svc 
kubernetes   192.168.3.1   <none>        443/TCP
```

I have seen lot of issues related to dashboard however was not able to get any solution , I am not sure how to proceed further,any pointer could be of great help

Comment: does `kubectl get pods -n kube-system -o wide` say anything interesting? are all system pods running ok, or have any of them crashed?

Comment: App pods are running okay but kube-dns and kubernetes-dashboard pods are failing.

Comment: kube-dns must be running in order to get the dashboard up. What does the logs for the dns pod say?

Comment: $ kubectl logs kube-dns-v20-nskvk -c kubedns -n kube-system

Comment: This shows  Failed to list *api.Service: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials (get services)
$kubectl logs kube-dns-v20-nskvk -c dnsmasq -n kube-system

Comment: dnsmasq container started but healthz container (kubectl logs kube-dns-v20-nskvk  healthz -n kube-system) failed with Healthz probe on /healthz-dnsmasq error: Result of last exec: nslookup: can't resolve 'kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local'

Comment: Is there a hard depenedency for kube-dns to run for kube-dashboard ? I thought they are not dependant on each other.

Comment: I have got kube-dns pod up and running using fix from the below link                 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34356694/cannot-start-skydns#, but kube-dashbaord still failing

Comment: Can you update the log output for the dashboard pod?

Comment: @HansKristian, thank you very much for providing inputs. I got it working . I am not sure what exactly was the issue. I rebuilt the entire cluster and it worked.